# Cannot execute code at UserInterFaceOnly set to True

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    wSheet.Protect Password:="Wordpass", _
    UserInterFaceOnly:=True    
Next wSheet

End Sub
```

It protects all worksheet in the workbook but allows macro to run.
However, this code:

```
wb.RefreshAll 'I've declared and set wb accordingly.
```

doesn't execute at all even though `UserIntergFaceOnly` is set to `True`.

Comment: how do you know it didn't execute? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: well it executes but the pivots doesn't refresh because the worksheets are protected. sorry what i meant is it executes but not the way i want it.

Comment: where are the pivots picking up data from?

Comment: from a different sheet within the same workbook. for the meantime what i did is i excluded the sheet with the pivots in protection and so the pivots refreshes. I just want to understand why it should behave that way? other codes execute fine except the `wb.RefreshAll`.

Comment: hmm, try an alternative that I gave in the post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userinterfaceonly` flag certainly doesn't work the way I would expect. Generally speaking, I set it, but I often find that I have to bracket things with `unprotect` and `protect`.  Whenever I get an error, or failure to do something, its the first thing I try.

I apologise for lack of specifics and I will post back later after surveying my code. To be honest, I'm usually so busy with trial and error due to lack of documentation for VBA that I haven't had time to document this type of behaviour yet.  But I will in the near future.

But meanwhile, I also try to make sure object reference are a qualified as possible so, in your case for example, I would try:

```
Thisworkbook.Refreshall
```

Or

```
Application.Thisworkbook.Refreshall
```

Or maybe even

```
application.workbooks(application.thisworkbook.name)
```

Failing that, bracket with `unprotect/protect contents:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True`

Comment: Like you, I would like to understand what are the exceptions for the protection behaviour...

Comment: For now I'll accept this answer. I did end up using `protect` and `unprotect` in my code since I'm after the execution speed. If somehow, somebody bump into this and have a different story then I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Protect Password:="Wordpass", _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next wSheet
End Sub

'~~> Change "Sheet1" to the relevant sheet which has the pivot   
Sub UpdatePivot()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each pt In .PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
            DoEvents
        Next pt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this is the code which i deviated from due to slow execution but it certainly works on `UserInterFaceOnly` set to `True`.

Comment: What happens if you add doevents after wb.refreshall in your original code?

Comment: it still doesn't refresh the pivots if sheet is protected.

Comment: for some legal reasons, no. but it is easy to reproduce i guess. or you aren't getting the same response?